# Adding to the end of a line in vi editor without leaving the home row

Tags: vi

When working in the vi editor normal mode, I can navigate such that the cursor appears "over" the right-most character on a line (block cursor). If I switch into insert mode and start typing, the last character on the line appears to the right of the text I'm adding. Is it possible to quickly add to the end of a line or otherwise move the cursor without using the arrow key or leaving the home row? I know the end key is also an option, but it also requires hand movement away from the home row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append to the end of the line with A. Here is a list of insert commands in vi

https://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html#A1.5